# Unique constraint at field in collection

Tags: hibernate-validator

is it possible to make this validation:

```
class Man {

@Unique
String name;
}

class Order {
@Valid
List<Man> manCollection;
}
```

where is unique logic is: every item in collection manCollection is unique.

Answer (score 0):

You could make this snippet ambiguous just by adding a Customer class that contains a List of Orders:

```
class Man {
  @Unique
  String name;
}

class Order {
  @Valid
  List<Man> manCollection;
}

class Customer {
  @Valid
  List<Order> orderCollection;
}
```

Then one couldn't possibly know whether the `Man` objects must be unique within a given Order or within a given Customer (or both).

So I don't think it's possible with this exact syntax, regardless of what the Bean Validation APIs allow.

What you could do is move the annotation to `manCollection`, e.g. `@UniqueMen List<Man> manCollection;`, and implement a `ConstraintValidator<List<Man>>`.

If it's useful to you, you could even make a more generic `@UniqueContent` annotation, but that would be much more complex. You would need to pass the target type as a parameter (`@UniqueContent(target = Man.class)`) and write a validator that parses annotations on the `target` class in its `initialize` method. Be careful to use some caching mechanism, though, because annotation parsing is quite slow.

Comment: thanks. i'll try to implement the target type as a parameter (@UniqueContent(target = Man.class).